# Changing active string c#

Tags: c#, string

im having some problem with c#. I would like to change a string which is changed half way though the code and is tested true or false later.

So far i have been having problems with this and referred to the internet. I couldn't really find anything.

Example..

```
if (LineIN == "silent")
{
    string silent = "true"; //Change string from false to true
}
```

Tester...

```
if (silent == "true") 
{
// Do something
}
```

Im using visual studios and it said i needed to create to string out side the if so i did. After that it was giving me more errors..

```
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
    Console.Write("RSA #: ");
    string LineIN = Console.ReadLine();

    if (LineIN == "silent")
    {
        string silent = "true";
    }
}

if (silent == "false") { // }
```

Comment: In one place you refer to silent and in the other you refer to speak.  Are they supposed to be the same variable?

Comment: yes sorry, that was a typo :l

Comment: What errors are you getting now?  How is LineIN instantiated?

Comment: First of all i get "The Name 'Silent' does not exist in current context"

Comment: Can you post some more of your code.

Comment: I have edited to post with the extra code

Answer (score 6):

As the error says, you will need to declare `silent` in a wider scope. For example:

```
void main()
{
    string silent = "false"; // silent is declared here in outer scope so it can be used in the second if()

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
    Console.Write("RSA #: ");
    string LineIN = Console.ReadLine();

    if (LineIN == "silent")
    {
        silent = "true";
    }

    if (silent == "true")
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If you declare the `silent` variable inside of an `if` statement, the variable will not be accessible outside of that block. Moving the declaration outside of the `if` allows you to access the variable later in the method and read/change the value, etc.

Alternatively, you can use a `bool` to store `true`/`false` values:

```
    bool silent = false; // silent is declared here in outer scope so it can be used in the second if()

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
    Console.Write("RSA #: ");
    string LineIN = Console.ReadLine();

    if (LineIN == "silent")
    {
        silent = true;
    }

    if (silent == true)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

The declaration of `silent` with an initial value of `false` is redundant, as the default value of a `bool` is `false` anyway. I added it just to make the change from `false` to `true` more obvious.

Comment: Very nice. But I would use a `bool`. OP is still learning ;-)

Comment: Correct. I would also use a `bool`, but the question was asking about changing the value of a `string`. Definitely OP should use `bool` :)

Comment: Is there something to allow me to use it in the 2nd if?

Comment: Yes, by declaring the variable outside of the first if, you can use it anywhere in that method. I also added code using a `bool` instead of `string` just to show you another option.

Comment: Of course, for style, I would use `bool silent = (LineIN == "silent");` if that's the only case you want to set it, and then just `if (silent)` because the `== true` is redundant for a bool.  But that's for version 2.0.  :)

Comment: Could remove the `bool` altogether too, and just do `if (LineIN == "silent") { // do something }` :)